# Animation quality on Instagram

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, principle-app

I've made an animation using Sketch + Principle + Photoshop. I exported the video as high quality 1080p MOV or MP4. But when I upload the video to Instagram, result is very bad. Here you can see the results: https://www.instagram.com/uxiconix/

How can I upload to Instagram without losing quality?

Comment: Hi linepisode. Your question has very little to do with Graphic Design. We are not Instagram or its developers, and we do not know how Instagram handles videos once you upload them. If the original quality of the videos is good, I'd suggest getting in touch with Instagram. Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @PieBie I disagree with closing this. Questions about image quality on internet, print, even facebook have been on topic here. Why shouldn't instagram be as well?

Comment: @Linepisode - the quality doesn't look terrible to me. What's wrong with it compared to the file on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because Instagram has it's own converter and it makes your video's smaller in size, so that it will save bandwidth and load faster.

Try optimizing your video before you upload it to Instagram. i.e: Export in .MP4 using h.264, at a bit-rate that will make your file size be less than 15MB. This is what i use most of the time and it works for me. Try playing with you export settings and see what works best.

But for most online videos .MP4 with h.264 encoding works best.